# Inserting a row and retrieving identity of new row in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, identity, sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to insert a row and get back the new row's identity with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO blah....;
SELECT @@IDENTITY as NewID;
```

I'm trying to execute both statements with a single invocation of a DbCommand object in C#... it doesn't seem work or I've got something wrong.

I've read that Compact Edition doesn't support executing multiple statements in a batch... but I also found this:

> If you want to run multiple queries simultaneously, you must include a new line character for each statement and a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.110).aspx

So does it work or not... and if so what am I missing?

(I realise I can execute two commands and that works fine, but I wonder if I'm missing something).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem work" [sic]? What happens? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like a doc error, it is the other way around. You can only execute a single statement per ExecuteNonQuery call.

Comment: Surprised if a doc error can be repeated at least 3 times for SQLCE [3.5 SP1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.100).aspx), [3.5 SP2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.105).aspx), and [4.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(SQL.110).aspx)? I've got really confused.

Answer (score 3):

You must define a output parameter to get identity value

```
sqlCommand Command = Conn.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = "insert into MyTable(Value1,Value2) values(MyValue,MyValue)"
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Command.CommandText = "select @ID = @@IDENTITY"
SqlParameter ID = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Command.Parameters.Add(ID);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int NewID = (int)ID.Value;
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I'm using DbCommand.ExecuteScalar() and it returns the new records identity fine.  It just needs to be a separate command, not a batched one.

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edtion only supports a single statement per command. [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/1d1d3267-dc29-470b-bb20-00487a39bc87/)

Comment: Also, it seems that you MUST "SELECT @@IDENTITY" against the same open connection that you have run "INSERT".

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of errors with `sql-server-ce` such as Direction couldn't be Output I got this to work.

```
public static long GetIdentity(this IDbConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return (long)(decimal)id;
}
```